# C'est quoi la différence entre la Sécurité Physique et la Sécurité Environmentale ?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot

Il existe une différence entre le sentiment de sécurité (psychique) : qui est un sentiment de quelqu'un qui est à l'abri du danger ET le sens de sécurité physique qui est relative à une situation présentant un minimum de risque. [Source Wiki](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9curit%C3%A9).

Ce que je cherche est un volet de la sécurité qui est physique ou environnementale ? j'ai du mal à faire la distinction.

Une premiere proposition serait :

1. securité physique concerne l'extérieur d'un local
2. sécurité environnementale concerne l'intérieur d'un local

Je suis un peu perdu, je ne sais pas où chercher ?

Comment: Le mot environnemental peut être employé désigner deux choses différentes. Ce qui est aux environs géographiques (ou ce qui nous entoure) et ce qui est lié à l'écosystème (ou la nature).

Answer (score 1):

"Sécurité physique" n'est pas vraiment une expression consacrée. La source Wiki citée emploie ce terme par opposition à l'aspect psychique du sentiment de sécurité. On a donc d'un côté la sécurité, le fait qu'une situation ne présente aucun risque (ou du moins peu de risque), de l'autre le sentiment de sécurité, le sentiment de quelqu'un qui se croit à l'abri de tout danger immédiat. Sécurité **réelle** contre sécurité **perçue**, autrement dit.

La "sécurité environnementale" est un cas particulier de la première définition, la sécurité "réelle", et s'applique à l'environnement au sens habituel. Assurer la sécurité environnementale, c'est donc veiller à ce que l'installation (usine, centre de traitement de déchets...) ou l'opération (chantier, pêche...) concernée n'ait pas d'impact négatif sur le monde qui l'entoure et plus particulièrement sur la nature : pas de pollution, pas de nuisance sonore, pas de contamination, pas d'introduction d'une espèce invasive, pas de destruction d'un milieu naturel...